# I have a question about the while loop in my code

Tags: java

How do I make the while loop stop forcefully by using playerHP when it becomes zero? Sometimes I would put an If statement around it, but it wouldn't work. New to coding so it would be cool to give some tips too. :)

```
public class RPGFight {

public static void main (String args[]) {
    int playerHP = 30;
    int boss1HP = 420;
    int exp = 0;

    System.out.println("You open the chamber door to see what lies beyond.");
    System.out.println("A demogorgon jumps out and attacks!");
    System.out.println("You deftly pull out your mighty blade and defend youself");

    while (boss1HP > 0) {
        if (boss1HP > 0) {
            int hit1 = (int)(Math.random()*20);
            int hit2 = (int)(Math.random()*20);
            int hit3 = (int)(Math.random()*20);
            int hit4 = (int)(Math.random()*20);
            int hit5 = (int)(Math.random()*20);
            int hit6 = (int)(Math.random()*20);
            int bossDMG = (int)(Math.random()*5);
            System.out.println("\nYou hit the demogorgon for " + hit1 + " points of damage");
            System.out.println("You hit the demogorgon for " + hit2 + " points of damage");
            System.out.println("You hit the demogorgon for " + hit3 + " points of damage");
            System.out.println("You hit the demogorgon for " + hit4 + " points of damage");
            System.out.println("You hit the demogorgon for " + hit5 + " points of damage");
            System.out.println("You hit the demogorgon for " + hit6 + " points of damage");
            System.out.println("You have been hit for " + bossDMG + " points of damage");
            playerHP -= bossDMG;
            boss1HP -= hit1+hit2+hit3+hit4+hit5+hit6;
        } 
        if (boss1HP < 0) {
            int expbattle = (int)(Math.random()*126+5);
            exp += expbattle;
            System.out.println("\nThe demogorgon falls to the floor, lifeless.");
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You earned " + expbattle + " points of experience.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Anyway there's no need to check 'if (boss1HP > 0)'... If your code reach that row boss1HP is always > 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a `break` immediately after you modify the `playerHP` after checking that is less than or equal to zero. Like,

```
playerHP -= bossDMG;
if (playerHP <= 0) {
    break;
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the if condition after 
**playerHP -= bossDMG;**

if (playerHP  < 1)
          break;

this will break the while loop when playerHP value is less than equal to 0.